# Servicestack.net Mini Profiler in razor view

Tags: servicestack, mvc-mini-profiler

Is it possible to use the mini profiler in service stack with the razor views?  It looks like the documentation only shows the profiler when using the json html report view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can include it using the same MVC include but include it `.AsRaw()` so it doesn't get HTML encoded, e.g:

```
@ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.RenderIncludes().AsRaw()
```

Example taken from this [RazorRockstars template](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/blob/master/src/RazorRockstars.WebHost/Views/Shared/HtmlReport.cshtml).