# No mini profiler for "no ceremony" pages in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I'd like to include profiling in my "No Ceremony" views - e.g. without controller/service, such as the default.cshtml or pages in the Razor Rockstars example.

I've tried to include

```
@ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.RenderIncludes().AsRaw()
```

in the .cshtml pages, as from the documentation and mentioned here ([Servicestack.net Mini Profiler in razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586343/servicestack-net-mini-profiler-in-razor-view)). This works perfectly for View pages (services with a HTML view applied), but there is no such luck for "controller less" pages - so called "No Ceremony" pages.

Since the controller-less pages also can include DB calls, it would also be useful to have SQL profiling here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should now be [resolved with this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/442f5a4aa15723416d6ba28fb11ad155b570f9b1) available from **v4.0.32+** that's [now on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).